# How can I parse [a / b] ? syntax error in Rebol?

Tags: rebol

I am having a problem with:

```
>> parse [a / b] ['a '/ 'b]
** Syntax Error: Invalid word-lit -- '
** Near: (line 1) parse [a / b] ['a '/ 'b]
>>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure but I feel this is some sort of elaborate (or not) advertising scheme.

Comment: I'm not quite sure but I feel there is some sort of pananoïds :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REBOL's interpreter has some limitations on what you can happily write on the command line. You can't get a **lit-word** by writing **'/** -- it throws an error because REBOL knows that **/** is the op! for division:

```
'/
** Syntax Error: Invalid word-lit -- '
```

But you can create '/ as a lit-word, starting with a string:

```
to-lit-word "/"
== '/
```

A solution to your code issue:

```
parse [a / b] compose ['a (to-lit-word "/") 'b]
=== true
```

- compose [...] -- means we'll selectively evaluate part of the block before the parse
- (...) -- is the part that is selectively evaluated, thus creating the desired '/ lit-word

Comment: Great just need a refinement now see below :)

Comment: See rather http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458139/rebol-parse-rule-with-compose-deep-and-append-function because it's another question

Comment: Nitpickin' here: but I think it's the special status of / for PATH! which probably breaks the parsing (as opposed to being the division operator).  Note that you can literal quote other ops just fine e.g. '* or '+ ...

Comment: Of course you can set up a specific rule: `dvdr: reduce [to-lit-word "/"]` and then use this in your main parse rule: `['a dvdr 'b]`