# rebol parse rule with compose/deep and append function

Tags: rebol

This works great (thanks to Sunanda's suggestion [How can I parse [a / b] ? syntax error in Rebol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452239/rebol-how-to-parse-a-b-syntax-error/1453205#1453205)):

```
attribute: copy []
class: copy []
definition-rule: compose/deep [some [set class word! 'is 'defined 'by 
[some [copy attribute to (to-lit-word "/") thru (to-lit-word "/") ]]
copy attribute to end]]
parse [Customer is defined by First Name / Last Name / Email] definition-rule
```

but I now need to add some append instructions (append output class)  and it doesn't work any more:

```
attribute: copy []
class: copy []
definition-rule: compose/deep [some [set class word! (append output class) 'is 'defined 'by 
[some [copy attribute to (to-lit-word "/") thru (to-lit-word "/") ]]
copy attribute to end]]
parse [Customer is defined by First Name / Last Name / Email] definition-rule
```

Comment: Well, let's see if Sunanda answers again. I don't quite understand why a tutorial is asking questions, but I'm prepared to be wrong.

Comment: I am happy to answer questions on REBOL (if I know the answer) on any forum where REBOL questions are asked. The REBOL community's utilisation of Stackoverflow so far is quite small -- mainly RebolTutorial asking questions, and several people (mainly me so far) responding. If that creates problems for anyone, then Reboltutorial could switch to one of the REBOL-specific forums for his/her Q&A support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the **compose** is eating all the expressions in parentheses. You are happy for it to eat the **(to-lit-word "/")** but you seriously do not want it to eat the **(append output class)** because that is intended for the **parse** dialect.

There is probably a cleverer approach, but this should work: remove the **compose** by doing the **lit-word** work outside of the parse rule...

```
attribute: copy []
class: copy []
output: copy ""
fs: to-lit-word "/"   ;; define a forward slash lit-word

definition-rule:  [
    some [set class word! (append output class) 'is 'defined 'by [
        some [copy attribute to fs thru fs]
    ]
    copy attribute to end]
    ]

parse [Customer is defined by First Name / Last Name / Email] definition-rule
== true
```

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do with this code, but it you want to extract the set of attributes at the end, then consider this change:

```
attribute: copy []
attributes: copy []
class: copy []
output: copy ""
fs: to-lit-word "/"   ;; define a forward slash lit-word

definition-rule:  [
    some [set class word! (append output class) 'is 'defined 'by [
        some [copy attribute to fs thru fs (append/only attributes attribute)]
    ]
    copy attribute to end (append/only attributes attribute)]
    ]

parse [Customer is defined by First Name / Last Name / Email] definition-rule

print ["==" class mold attributes]

== Customer [[First Name] [Last Name] [Email]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I needed the second example for doing this:

attribute: copy []
class: copy []
fs: to-lit-word "/" 
output: copy ""


definition-rule:  [
    some [set class word! (append output join class "|") 'is 'defined 'by [
        some [copy attribute to fs thru fs (append output join attribute ";")]
    ]
    copy attribute to end (append output attribute)]
]

parse [Customer is defined by First Name / Last Name / Email] definition-rule
probe output

Answer (score 0):

I repost code in comment as it isn't readable, what I wanted to do exactly was this:

```
attribute: copy []
class: copy []
fs: to-lit-word "/" 
output: copy ""


definition-rule:  [
    some [set class word! (append output join class "|") 'is 'defined 'by [
        some [copy attribute to fs thru fs (append output join attribute ";")]
    ]
    copy attribute to end (append output attribute)]
]

parse [Customer is defined by First Name / Last Name / Email] definition-rule
probe output
```